# Reference to various tables

Tags: sql

Well, I'm in a middle of some design issue.
I'm trying to built kinda universal commenting system for my site.
So I started with two tables:

**Comment_node** has many **Comments**

Now I want to be able to attach my cool comment system to various places on my site. For example to blog_posts and to user_pages.

**blog_posts** has one **comment_node**

**user_pages** has one (different) **comment_node**

So I ended up in idea of storing additional **comment_node_id** field in blog_posts and user_pages tables. But the problem here is in the fact that this connection is unidirectional - I can get Comment node from either blog posts and user pages, but having comment_node I cannot find which other table uses it.

Sure I may store 'linked_table' string in comment_nodes or something, but I suppose that will kill my database design.

Is there a nice way to achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your idea is correct. Alter your Comment_node table and add following columns

```
| commentable_type | commentable_id |
```

The commentable_type column contains a string with the name of the referenced table (from your example, either blog_posts or user_pages) and the commentable_id contains the id of either the blog_post or a user_page (depending on the commentable_type column).

Then add a foreign key to both the blog_post and user_page table to reference your Comment_node.

I've designed these kind of comment systems before, usually my approach is

```
commentable_type [0..n] <--> [1] commentings [1] <--> [0..n] comment
```

My commentings table corresponds to your Comment_node (if I'm assuming this correctly). In my opinion this is the best way to achieve this.

EDIT: You could then perform a left join as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Comment_node c
LEFT JOIN Blog_post b
ON c.commentable_id = b.id
WHERE c.commentable_type = 'blog_post'
```

Comment: But will this allow me to LEFT JOIN blog_post from comment_node?

Comment: But I won't be able to select corresponding table in one query. I will have to have number of queries equal to number of commentable_types, right?

Comment: @undsoft: If you leave off the "WHERE c.commentable_type = 'blog_post'" all the commentable types for a given blog_post.id should be returned.

Comment: Do you mean you could not select the Blog_post table in the same query? Cause, that is certainly not the case, you can refer to all field of your blog_post table when you're LEFT JOINing it.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: that's not correct. You need to specify the commentable_type, otherwise you would wire for example user_page Comment_nodes to a blog_post

Comment: Ok, I suppose that's the best solution. Thanks